# Calling one javascript in other using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm want to call one module from one javascript to another. Currently i download demo of [GiftedMessanger](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-messenger)

And i created my own code of react native (ios), i add all dependency of GiftedMessanger in my code and it successfully downloaded all node modules. 
Now in GiftedMessanger demo code index.ios.js contains,

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry
} = React;


AppRegistry.registerComponent('GiftedMessengerExample', () => require('./Navigation'));
```

and all code running properly. 
Same thing i doing in my code. I want to call GiftedMessanger as a separate page on button click so written code,

```
var MessageBox = require('./Navigation');

var MyCode = React.createClass({

  _openGiftedMessanger(){
    return (<MessageBox />);
  },

  render: function() {
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.imButton}
            onPress={this._openGiftedMessanger}>
            <Text>Open Chat Room</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  }
});
```

The above now open Gifted messanger view. And on console also not throwing error. Where is my mistake, calling the javascript code.

Comment: are you using es6 syntax or not? your `_openGiftedMessanger()` is es6 syntax and your `render: function()` is es5. do you have a compiler like babel to compile es6 back to es5? that could be the problem

Comment: Thank you @JohnRuddell well, i'm using all lasted version. That means yeah i'm using es6 syntax.

Comment: @JohnRuddell how to get know my compiler babel is support es6 to es5?

Comment: You have to tell it to, it should be simple, but a simple Google search should be able to give you the answer, I don't know what your setup is on my end

Comment: @John Ruddell, sometimes few hints also support to understand big theory. Don't be rage like attitude.

Comment: not sure what you are saying.. I'm not raging? like I said a simple google search can show how to transpile es6 to es5. http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/03/09/transpiling-es6-to-es5-using-babel.html its super easy to type a search query like `babel convert es6 to es5` in a google search bar and look at the results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this code:

```
_openGiftedMessanger(){
    return (<MessageBox />);
  },
```

To replace the current view with a new view, use the Navigator or NavigatorIOS component. The new code should look like:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  title: 'Gifted messenger',
  component: MessageBox
});
```